# Filtering a table based on the average of a full column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tried to filter a table based on the average of a column, but somehow it doesn't work. It doesn't return anything. The average is about 102 and replacing the AVG clause with it does return the correct rows.

How can I get this to work properly?

```
SELECT
ce.customer_id,
ce.first_name,
ce.total

FROM
(SELECT 
p.customer_id,
c.first_name,
SUM(p.amount) AS total

FROM payment as p
JOIN customer as c ON p.customer_id=c.customer_id
GROUP BY p.customer_id,c.first_name) AS ce

GROUP BY ce.customer_id,ce.first_name,ce.total

HAVING ce.total > AVG(ce.total)
```

Comment: based on the query,`ce.total`,`AVG(ce.total)` will have the same value.so you don't get any rows. show us some sample data and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: You want values where the sum per client is greater than the average sum of all clients?

Comment: Yes @RossBush , that is exactly my intention.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has more than one error.  The outer `GROUP BY` does not make sense.

My recommendation is to use window functions.  In this case, you want the average of the total, so this looks like:

```
SELECT ce.customer_id, ce.first_name, ce.total
FROM (SELECT p.customer_id, c.first_name, SUM(p.amount) AS total,
             AVG(SUM(p.amount)) OVER () as avg_total
      FROM payment p JOIN
           customer c
           ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
      GROUP BY p.customer_id, c.first_name
     ) ce
WHERE ce.total > avg_total
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I also have not used the OVER() statement before. I am surprised to see this allows the aggregators to be nested, as I was not able to nest aggregators before.